# "Next" not working in loop when IF statement is true

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to check a cell which contains a unique ID (concatenation of several columns) in the current row and compare it to the row above it's unique ID.  If the values are the same, I want to copy the current line and insert this copy in a new row located two rows above the current row.  If the ID's are not the same, I want to do nothing and move to the next row on the sheet.

The code below runs without errors, and works correctly until an ID match is found.  The code copies and inserts as I require, but it acts like it is starting the "IF" statement again for the same line (the "next" does not advance to analyze the next row).  So I end up getting endless copies and inserts of the first line that has a matched Unique ID to the row above it.

```
Sub CopyAndInsert
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SelectionRNG = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A2:CX" & LastRow)
    For Each rngrow In SelectionRNG.Rows
        rngrow.Copy
        If rngrow.Cells(1, 102) = rngrow.Cells(0, 102) Then   'checks if row CX is equal to the row above it (same column)
            rngrow.Cells(2, 1).Offset(-2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Please note  if the rows do not match in the unique ID column (CX) then the "next" does work as expected and continues onto the next row.  The issue of not advancing only occurs when the ID's do match and the copied row is inserted.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: because you are inserting row in there and subsequently changing the initial range of loop.

Comment: When inserting or deleting rows it is good practice to iterate through the list from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Write `Next ` within if loop. And outside as well

Comment: @SanjayKumaar wouldn't this cause an error because there would be 2 `Next`'s and only 1 `For`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks - that makes logical sense, not sure why I didn't stucture this way to begin with.  I'll use J.Fox's solution below in short term while I restructure to loop from bottom up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tying the loop to a variable and manually increasing it by 1 to skip the added row seems to work:

```
Sub CopyAndInsert()
Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
lastRow = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To lastRow
    If Cells(x, 102) = Cells(x - 1, 102) Then
        Cells(x - 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A" & x + 1 & ":" & "CX" & x + 1).Copy Cells(x - 1, 1)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This does work, but throws off a bit of my code that I did not include in my original question.  The code (shown below) is designed to add the values found in Column CK for the "matching" rows and places the sum value into the newly inserted "copy" row.

    `rngrow.Cells(-1, 89) = rngrow.Cells(0, 89) + rngrow.Cells(1, 89)`

I'm having trouble reformatting my rngRow to your "Range" Format -- any suggestions?

Comment: Putting `Cells(x-1,89).Formula = Cells(x,89).Value + Cells(x+1,89).Value` on the row before `x = x + 1` should do the trick

Comment: I did run into an issue with your code, if the data has 4 rows with ID's that match in a row, it ends up inserting three new rows, when it should have only added 2.  I'm not sure but this may be solvable to looping from the bottom to the top and adding the "copied" row below the two matching lines - what do you think?

Comment: If 4 rows have ID's that match, why wouldn't it copy three times? It seems like when you have M matching ID's in a row (where M >= 2), that you would end up with M - 1 rows being copied. 1st iteration: Check row 1 v row 0 = no match. 2nd iteration: Check row 2 v row 1 = match. 3rd iteration: Check row 3 v row 2 = match. 4th iteration: Check row 4 v row 3 = match.

Comment: I was able to work through my problem by changing `For x = 3 To lastRow` to `For x = lastRow To 3 Step -1` and `x = x + 1` to `x = x - 1`